# Linker error: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 when building console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile this code is Visual Studio 2015:

```
int main()
{
    double* pvalue  = NULL; 
    pvalue  = new double;   

    *pvalue = 29494.99;     
    cout << "Value of pvalue : " << *pvalue << endl;

    delete pvalue;         

    return 0;
}
```

And i'm getting this compile error:

1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

Is this a Visual Studio problem? Should I reinstall it?

Comment: When you created your project, did you select "new Win32 application" or "new Console Application"?

Comment: Hahaha, that's it, thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

I started a Win application, not a console application.
Dumb mistake.